# How to set just only a side of WPF control margin?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, margin

I'm trying set a margin of a Image Control top margin, I can get this value with `Margin.Top`, but why can I set this with `image1.Margin.Top = 5;`?

How to can I set just this only value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the property accessor does not give you a reference to the object.  It is simply a wrapper around a `DependencyProperty`, which returns the value via `GetValue`.  If you want to change that item, you must do this:

```
Thickness margin = image1.Margin;
margin.Top = 5;
image1.Margin = margin;
```